# ScrollView screens similar to main menu in android

Tags: java, android

i am trying to add a scroll screen layout in my app just similar to `main screen scroll` of any android mobile. How can i Add such a screen in my activity.

Check the image below.
[image]

Comment: how would i add such a scrollable screen in my app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). The ViewPager is also included in the  Support library, so you can use it on HC< . It works excactly like this.

There are also custom implementations of the ViewPager, which increases its possibillities e.g.: [The ViewPager from Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/).

Comment: Jack Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator should do the job.

Comment: can you give me any idea how can i add those circles :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using "SwipeView"

A SwipeView is an Android UI view similar to the homescreens.  You have several similar panes of content that you access by swiping left and right.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with [Android ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow/) or [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jack Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator, it should work for you.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/